# What is the most appropriate way to concatenate with MFC's CString

Tags: c++, mfc, concatenation, c-strings

I am somewhat new to C++ and my background is in Java.  I am working on a hdc printing method.
I would like to know the best practice for concatenating a combination of strings and ints into one CString.  I am using MFC's CString.

```
int i = //the current page
int maxPage = //the calculated number of pages to print


CString pages = ("Page ") + _T(i) + (" of ") + _T(maxPage);
```

I would like it to look like 'Page 1 of 2'.  My current code does not work. I am getting the error:

> Expression must have integral or enum type

I have found more difficult ways to do what I need, but I want to know if there is a simple way similar to what I am trying.  Thanks!

Comment: The question is why would you want to use MFC and its ancient classes, rather than normal C++ strings (i.e. `std::string`)? Unless you have to maintain a legacy MFC codebase, of course.

Comment: I was asked by my employer to use MFC when creating my application.  I use the following with the HDC printer.       CString str = m_CListCtrl.GetItemText(startrow, 0);
      dcPrinter.TextOut(startx+10, starty+1, _T(str), strlen(str));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's [MFC's CString class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx), then you probably want [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6.aspx) which is a sprintf-alike for it:

```
CString pages;
pages.Format(_T("Page %d of %d"), i, maxPage);
```

i.e. you can assemble the string using regular [printf-format specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) substituting in the numbers at runtime.

Comment: This was chosen as the best answer because it was the most simple solution for using MFC's CString.  I have edited my original question.

Comment: Use This   'CString MESSAGE, MESSAGE1;
 MESSAGE1 = CString("Elmer jacobs");
 MESSAGE = CString("K") + MESSAGE1;
 pOutPut = (CStatic*)GetDlgItem(DK);
 pOutPut->SetWindowTextW(MESSAGE);'

Comment: @Dinesh  So just CString concatenation? I don't think that's better here, where we have more parts and integers too. Also the SetWindowText (you probably want without the 'W' in the general case) isn't needed for this question, did you mean to post this somewhere else?

Comment: @Rup  Thanks Very Much

Answer (score 3):

`std::string` has all you need:

```
auto str = "Page " + std::to_string(i) + " of " + std::to_string(maxPage);
```

As stated correctly in the comment, you can access the underlying C-string via `str.c_str()`. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b721396b64aeb0e4) is a live working example.

Comment: Alright. I like the idea of just using str.c_str().  However I am getting the Error: More than one instance of overloaded function "std::to_string".

Answer (score 3):

You can use also stringstream classes

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::ostringstream textFormatted;

  textFormatted << "Page " << i << " of " << maxPage;

  // To convert it to a string
  std::string s = textFormatted.str();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++11 you can use `std::to_string`: `std::string pages = std::string("Page ") + std::to_string(i) + (" of ") + std::to_string(maxPage);`

If you don't have C++11 you can use an `ostringstream` or `boost::lexical_cast`.